# Group of astronauts discover grass growing on the Moon

Tags: story-identification, movie, astronauts, moon

I saw a movie a few years ago about a group of astronauts who discovered grass growing on the moon. Unfortunately, that's as much as I know for sure. I *believe* it also involved the following:

- One of them was injured
- They removed their helmets
- They may have been hallucinating

Comment: Did they also discover a farm on the moon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure it was the moon? Could it have been Mars? In Red Planet (2000), mankind attempts to terraform Mars by seeding the planet with this special grass. It appears to have failed. The first manned mission to Mars discovers that the grass is growing on one section of Mars and generating oxygen. They discover why the grass is not growing any where else on the planet. There are worms in the sand that have developed an appetite for the grass and for human flesh.

Comment: A good guess. Red Planet was my first thought too. In addition to the grass, the other scenes described fit as well.

Comment: Yes, I thought they did, but it has been a long time since I saw it. So I wasn't as sure about the other scenes.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I must have been mixing it up with Apollo 18.

Comment: While I agree with your suggestion, I disagree that it was grass, special or otherwise. It was green algae used to terraform the planet. When the algae stopped growing, they sent up the Mars-1 crew to check it out. There are scenes with vast green fields, but it's algae not grass, and they didn't "discover" it, they knew it would be there in some quantity. Interestingly, they called the bugs "nematodes", but they were represented more like cockroaches than microscopic worms.